# Swift Process - execute command error

Tags: swift, bash, macos, terminal

I'm trying to execute the "history" command from a Mac App written in Swift.

```
@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

shell("history")
```

It always return me this error:

```
env: history: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong? It's really possible to work with the user command line history from a Mac App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using certain built-in `GNU` commands with `NSTask` (which are considered "interactive" like `history`) usually requires that environment variables are set so that the shell knows what to return, for example:

```
private let env = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment
```

This can be difficult since not all users obviously are using the same environment variables or shell for that matter. An alternative would be to use bash commands in the `NSTask` that don't require getting/setting up the environment:

```
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["-c", "cat -n ${HOME}/.bash_history"]

let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

print(output!)
```

The resulting output should resemble the numbered format of the actual shell history.

Comment: in the same script, how can I export dates? "export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\'%m/%d - %H:%M:%S: \'" return me the same 'No such file or directory '

Answer (score 1):

The `history` command is an internal bash command. As such, the correct syntax is:

```
$ bash -C history
```

In your `shell` function:

```
task.arguments = ["-C"] + args
```

Comment: @Marco There was a typo... please try again now.